# what kind of chord progession is this?

Tags: chords, key

im quite new in music theory and i really dont understand what he is doing here.
is he changing the key after every chord?
he talks about c minor being the root note. after that he switches to c# which would be off the key?
what kind of chord progession is this? does it have a name? i have a really hard time figuring out what is happening here :( it sounds so good tho!

thanks for helping!

Answer (score 8):

He is doing this:

`Cm Db => Fm Gb => Bbm Cb => Ebm Fb => ...`

What I hear is a continuous modulation up in perfect fourths. The chords `Cm Db Fm` can be heard in the key of F minor. The F minor chord is then re-interpreted as the Vm chord of the next key (Bbm) etc. So what you have is

```
key
Fm:  Cm Db Fm
Bbm:       Fm Gb Bbm
Ebm:             Bbm Cb Ebm
...
```

Answer (score 6):

@MattL already pointed out the three chord pattern.

With Roman numerals the basic harmonic template is `v VI i`. That's a minor `v`. The chords are diatonic, but technically non-functional. I only mention this as a *kind* of progression. When chords are treated non-functionally you can use unconventional root progressions that aren't like familiar patterns such as `ii V I`, and they can sound pretty cool with a more drifting feel.

Then a harmonic pattern is repeat by transposing you can call it a *harmonic sequence*. Sequences can be either diatonic or chromatic. In this case the sequence is chromatic and shifts into different modes.

Instead of having a more common name like *turnaround* `ii V I` or *substitution* `ii bII I` you could call this kind of progression...

*A diatonic, non-functional, sequential progression.*

That is a mouthful, but it really does describe the *kind* of progression.